# Div alignment wrong : Right hand middle aligned

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have two div's centrally, the left aligns okays, the right hand one aligns middle, I don't understand why the right hand is aligning like that.

```
#pageWrapper
{
    /* display: flex; */
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    text-align: left;
    padding: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navbar
{     
    width: 180px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    opacity: .8;
    display: inline-block;   
}
<div id="pageWrapper">
    <div id="topBar">
    ----- navbar stuff goes in here 
    </div>

    <div style="width: 700px; display: inline-block; margin: 0;">
    ----- topbar goes in here 
    </div>
```

Test site: [here](http://cafe.tokenbay.co.uk/)

Comment: You want the bottom "stuff goes here" div to go on the right?

Comment: can you draw a picture of how you want it to look?

Comment: @Edward Yes, the second dive should be on right, ideally if I shrunk the browser it would go under the left one

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in your site you have in this div:

```
<div style="width: 700px; display: inline-block; margin: 0;">
    ----- topbar goes in here 
</div>
```

You have a div with a ***float: left.*** You need to change that to ***float: right*** and then the div will look centered because of your width:700px.

Change it to a wider div and the div will move to the right.

To see it is actually right and not centered you should change the width to something like:

```
<div style="width: 80%; display: inline-block; margin: 0;">
    ----- topbar goes in here 
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the float: left?

Comment: Giving the parent div of the right column `float: right` does appear to solve the problem. But it didn't have `float: left`. It had no `float` rule at all.

Comment: @Michael_B and Ziv that does thank you.  If I shink the screen it now moves under the top block (wahoo), but centrally aligned, is there a way to stop that?

Comment: @PaulMorriss, you should post enough code in the question so we can reproduce the problem and make adjustments.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had posted enough

Comment: post all of the relevant code, no code should be on external site. Did you change the width? if you will change it to something like 80% you will see it is not centered.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `width: 50%` for both boxes.

This is your result:

[image]